# CSS not working on id on jsp

Tags: css, jsp

On my jsp page `outputText` tag when I use id, my css style sheet doesn't pick up on it, but when I change it to class it works.

jsp:

```
<h:outputText id="namelabel" value="Name:" />
```

css:

```
#namelabel {

    font-weight: bold;
}
```

When I used the id for the parent `<h:form>` it does make the font bold for that whole form, so I don't understand the difference, could anyone explain? Feel like im missing something obvious..

At the moment its not a problem, but Im also wondering for future reference if I wanted to give unique CSS rules to that particular `outputText`, or would I just add another class rule to it? I suppose Im asking about best practice here too.

Im also using ajax, netbeans and deploying to GlassFish.

Comment: This should work, when not, either the id dynamically changed or another rule, later in the CSS (or script wise) set the font to something else. If you right click on the element and chose "Inspect", you like will be able to see which in the dev. tools that popup

Comment: @LGSon many thanks for your input, I used the other answer to actually change the code, but this was helpful to know and I could then see on the 'inspect' how the id has been changed as per the other persons advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF will change the id of the input box component. The id will changed to following form

```
form_name:component_id
```

Use following code for styles

```
form_name\:id
```

Ex:

```
<h:form name="testForm">
<h:outputText id="namelable" value="Name:" />
</h:form>
<style>
#testForm\:namelabel{
font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```